# How to update table properties from related table in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've recently started with ASP.NET and I must say that I like it a lot. But in every relationship, you must hit some obstacle here and there. Here is mine:

My starting project includes creating simple schools system for managing students. I have several tables (Students, StudentAddresses, Grades, and Courses).

Here are problematic two tables:

1) Student table:

```
  public Student()
        {

            this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
        }

        public int StudentId { get; set; }

        [Required] 
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "The name must have over 2 and under 50 characters!")] // stavlja ograničenje na duljinu stringa u bazi
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required] 
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "The name must have over 2 and under 50 characters!")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public int CurrentGradeId { get; set; }
        public Grade CurrentGrade { get; set; }
        public virtual StudentAdress Address { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
```

2) StudentAddress table:

```
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Adress2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }

        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
```

In short, I'm trying to update StudentAddresses properties (to be more precise Address1 property for Student) while inside Student edit Action Method.

Here is View for Edit student:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Student</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StudentId)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurrentGradeId, "CurrentGradeId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CurrentGradeId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CurrentGradeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address.Address1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.Address1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.Address1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally here is Edit Action Method for StudentsController:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "StudentId,Name,Surname,CurrentGradeId")] Student student  )
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        // getting student id for current studentid
        StudentAdress addresa = db.Addresses.Find(student.StudentId);

        // trying to bind input value
        addresa.Address1 = student.Address.Address1.ToString();

        // saving new value in StudentAddresses field Address1
        db.Entry(addresa).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.CurrentGradeId = new SelectList(db.Grades, "GradeId", "GradeName", student.CurrentGradeId);
    return View(student);
}
```

So, in Edit method, I want to save new input value for Address1 inside Edit method for Student table. Or to put it simpler, I want to update field Address1 in StudentAddress class while Editing Student class

**UPDATE 1**

So, let's say that I've figure it out but I'm still wondering if it is proper and right way of doing it.

In Student Edit action method I added `addresa.Address1 = Request.Form["Address.Address1"];` where I updated field with attribute `name=Address.Address1` and it did a trick but I'm wondering if it is right way of doing it?

Keep in mind that I've tried this

```
**addresa.Address1 = student.Address.Address1;**
```

but using this "cleaner" approach gave me:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

Could I updated Address.Address1 field using some other approach?

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "StudentId,Name,Surname,CurrentGradeId")] Student student  )
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {


                StudentAdress addresa = db.Addresses.Find(student.StudentId);

                // newly added line
                addresa.Address1 = Request.Form["Address.Address1"];
                db.Entry(addresa).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.CurrentGradeId = new SelectList(db.Grades, "GradeId", "GradeName", student.CurrentGradeId);
            return View(student);
        }
```

Comment: What issue you are facing with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Your relationships are wrong.

In your `StudentAddress` model we can see the `StudentId` foreign key which means relationship between `Student` and `StudentAddress` is one to many. But in your `Student` model you have `virtual StudentAdress Address` which should be `ICollection<StudentAdress> Addresses`.

And in your add/edit you could just do:

```
var student = context.Student.Find(1);

student.Addresses.Add(new StudentAdress {
    Address1 = "Ul. Janka Leskovara",
    City = "Pregrada",
    ZipCode = 49218,
    Country = "Hrvatska"
});

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yes thank you but how can I bind value for Addres1 from Student Edit View for that particular  student id ?